# Check Mount Directory

Tags: linux, mount, logging, raspbian

I have raspberry pi and have microsd with raspbian from which the system is loading and the HDD on which I write logs. I encountered such a problem that sometimes the disk falls off and the logs begin to be written to the microsd in the same directory where the HDD was mounted. How can I prohibit writing logs to a USB flash drive, and write only when the drive is mounted? I write logs very often and there is no possibility to check whether a disk is mounted at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If the logging isn't performed by `root`, it would be sufficient to make the mount point read only, for that use `chmod -R 0444 /mountpoint`. However, `root` would still be able to write into that directory, so in that case you might need to use `chattr -i /mountpoint`, which would make it completely unwritable.

These attributes won't carry over after mounting, since the permissions are inherited from the parameters set in the `fstab`.

Keep in mind that by restricting writing into the mount point directory when nothing's mounted there would present a different problem: how would your logging tools handle denied write permissions?